# preg_replace Double quotes anywhere in string

Tags: php, preg-replace

how can i replace double quotes anywhere is the string ?

i have a code like this

$product_info['description'] contains: "Some text go" here

```
preg_replace('/[\n\r]/', '', strip_tags(html_entity_decode($product_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')))
```

than in html i have a code like this

```
"description": "<?php echo $rich_snippets['description']; ?>",
```

Result (Wrong)

> ""Some text go" here"

Looking to get (Correct)

> "Some text go here"

Comment: Just add a `"` to your character class …?

Comment: (_Should_ they even be removed, or are you just looking for a workaround because otherwise they cause syntax errors? In that case, you should not be outputting string values manually, but go with JSON to begin with.)

Comment: @misorude sorry didnt get what you are saying

Comment: What is not to get here? You know what the code you currently have does, yes? And what `/[\n\r]/` actually is?

Comment: @misorude english is not my first lang. im not 100% sure what you are saying or mean sorry about that ,   \n\r should remove new line and br

Comment: Where does `$rich_snippets['description']` come from? And what is its content?

Comment: `[\n\r]` is a so-called character class in regular expressions. Those two in here are getting replaced with an empty string already - so if you want to remove double quotes, too, just add one in that list - `[\n\r"]`

Comment: @misorude yes that is work correct